# Which recent Linux dsitribution has libQtGui.a 4.8 among it’s pacakge files?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, qt, arm, centos

My Linux distribution doesn’t provides a static archive for Qt. And it turns out compiling Qt4 is a nightmare.

There are lot of Qt compiled packages both as rpm or deb. But where I can find a distribution which provides static version compiled for aarch64 (arm64) ?

Comment: This is a question where you can compile and upload in order to write the answer. This is for compiling my own project, so there’s no distribution compatibility involved.

Comment: Afraid this question is not fitting this site. This is *Software Recommendations* – not *Download Locations:* We answer requests in the form "what software meets {specific requirements}". Related topics on Meta: [Are “where can I find the source of this dead project”-questions on topic?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2538/185) // [Is it on topic to ask where to download specific drivers?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1224/185) In both cases, the answer is: off-topic.

Comment: @Izzy now that I'm asking for a distro, is it ok ?

Comment: I still find it a bit borderline (with static QT as the only requirement). But I let the community decide. So far noone has marked it for closure ;)